# Is this relation on the set ${1,2,3,4}$ transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Based the definition that a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is called transitive:
$∀_a ∀_b ∀_c (((a,b)∈R∧(b,c)∈R)→(a,c)∈R)$

I thought the relation ${(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4)}$ would be transitive due to the case: $$((1,3)\in R \land (3,4)\in R)\to (1,4)\in R$$

If it's not would adding $(1,1)$ to the relation make it transitive?

Comment: We have $2\sim_R 3$ and $3\sim_R 1$ but we do not have $2\sim_R 1$.  It's not enough to check transitivity for one combination of terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to check transitivity in one, or a couple of cases, it has to hold in all cases for which it makes sense.  Providing a single counterexample is, however, enough to disprove transitivity.

Here we have $2\sim_R 3\;$ and $3\sim_R 1\;$ but we do not have $2\sim_R 1$, so transitivity fails.