# Understanding transitive relations on set $\{0,1,2,3\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm having a hard time understanding the transitive property for the following relation. I believed it to be transitive and I can't determine why it is not:

Example 1:
$$\{(0,0),(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$$

Case 1: $((0,0)\in R \wedge (0,0) \in R) \to (0,0) \in R$

Case 2: $((1,1)∈R∧(1,1)∈R)→(1,1)∈R$

Case 3: $((1,3)∈R∧(3,1)∈R)→(1,1)∈R$

Case 4: $((2,2)∈R∧(2,2)∈R)→(2,2)∈R$

Case 5: $((2,3)∈R∧(3,2)∈R)→(2,2)∈R$

Case 6: $((3,1)∈R∧(1,3)∈R)→(3,3)∈R$

Case 7: $((3,2)∈R∧(2,3)∈R)→(3,3)∈R$

Case 8: $((3,3)∈R∧(3,3)∈R)→(3,3)∈R$

Since $∀_a ∀_b ∀_c (((a,b)∈R∧(b,c)∈R)→(a,c)∈R)$ is true for all cases, is it not the case that this is a transitive relation?

Comment: Just as with [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177601/is-this-relation-on-the-set-1-2-3-4-transitive) all you need is one counterexample.  Here we have $2\sim_R 3$ and $3\sim_R 1$ but we do not have $2\sim_R 1$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not check all cases. It is not transitive because both $(1,3)$ and $(3,2)$ belong to it, whereas $(1,2)$ doesn't.